# How to add the ability for a C# .NET core controller to handle extensions to the object it deals with?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I currently have a controller that handles user objects at the /users endpoint. It works exactly how I need up to this point, however I would now like to add an extension for users to add some attributes. The problem then is the controller methods expect user objects so even if I try and post an extended user all the non base user attributes are thrown away. Is there a way then that I can make the post more generic to handle both?

For reference here is my current post signature.

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<User>> Post(User item)
    {
```

Comment: You would need an action with your extended class type as a parameter. The deserializer needs to know the exact type to construct.

Comment: What would you do then? Better have two methods `PostUser(User)`, `PostSpecificUser(SpecificUser)` and then think about how you pass it to your services.

Comment: Is this .Net or .Net Core?  In both cases you can create your own Model binder that will construct any object you want and attempt to pass that to the controller method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone. I was actually able to solve it by having the POST take a JObject. In my case the extension users are guaranteed to have a specific attribute so I check if that exists in the JObject then bind it to one of the classes depending on if it is.

Answer (score -1):

> *"Is there a way then that I can make the post more generic to handle both (`User` and `ExtendedUser` objects)"*

You could check if the `User` is actually an `ExtendedUser` (using the `as` keyword to create a new object). If it is an `ExtendedUser` (i.e. the new object is not `null`), then you can access the extended properties from a single method that accepts a `User` type:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<User>> Post(User user)
{
    // Check if 'user' is an 'ExtendedUser', and if it is, use the extended properties
    var extUser = user as ExtendedUser;
    if (extUser != null)
    {
        // Do something with extUser here
    }

    // Carry on with typical 'User' activities
}
```

And now the sample code above works just the same, and produces the same output, with only a single method.

Comment: This is not how the ModelBinder works, it does not magically know that because there are extra properties it creates some other object that derives from `User`.